# SMS plugin not working in ionic 4 and app?

Tags: android, cordova, sms, cordova-plugins, ionic4

i'm trying to use sms plugin to send sms but it always crashs whenever i try to send sms and also sms.hasPermission() is always false? Please let me know how to request sms permission and send sms ? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms

```
        this.sms.hasPermission().then(hasPermission => {
          console.log("hasPermission",hasPermission);

          if(hasPermission){
            this.sms.send(i.phoneNumber, message, {
              replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
              android: {
                  intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                  //intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
              }
          });
          } else{
            console.log("eror");
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

correct  implementation of https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions

prior accessing any native functionality on android ionic project is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic SMS plugin might have some issue so i have taken reference from https://github.com/akashpjames/smsApp/blob/master/src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts and it's working fine